# Different input size in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, input

The following code works accurately in every browser but IE. The inputs have a width of 300px, but in IE it gets the right size only when it's focused. I tried max-width and min-width aswell but it doesn't seem to work. I attach an image, as you can see the inactive inputs are bigger:

http://kepfeltoltes.hu/131104/IE_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg

And here is the code and a fiddle: 
HTML:

```
<div id="label">
<form action="" method="post">
<label for="name">
<input class="input1" type="text" placeholder="Your name" name="name" id="name" />
</label>
<label for="E-mail">
<input class="input1" type="text" placeholder="Your e-mail" id="email"/>
</label>
<label for="Subject">
<input class="input1" type="text" placeholder="Subject" id="subject" />
</label>
<label for="Message">
<textarea class="input2" name="message" rows="20" cols="20" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
</label>
<label>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#label {
    width:960px;
    height:600px;
}
input {
    width:300px;
    max-width:300px;
    min-width:300px;
    -moz-border-color: #0d1025;
    -moz-border-width:medium;
    border-color: #0d1025;
    border-width:medium;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-style:solid;
}
.input1 {
    width:300px;
    max-width:300px;
    height:30px;
    display:block;
}
.input2 {
    width:650px;
    max-width:650px;
    max-height:270px;
    height:270px;
    margin-left:320px;
    margin-top:-144px;
    border-color: #0d1025;
    border-width:medium;
    border-style: solid;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #0d1025;
   font-style:italic;
   padding-left:15px;
   font-weight:bold;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #0d1025;  
   font-style:italic;
   padding-left:15px;
   font-weight:bold;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #0d1025;  
   font-style:italic;
   padding-left:15px;
   font-weight:bold;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #0d1025;  
   font-style:italic;
   padding-left:15px;
   font-weight:bold;
}
input:focus { 
    outline: none !important;
    border-color:#009bcf;
    /*box-shadow: 0 0 5px #009bcf;*/
}

textarea:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border-color:#009bcf;
}
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/h2core/hLxf6/

What did I do wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://oi41.tinypic.com/z4rk9.jpg try this

Comment: Which version of IE?
In IE9 its running similar to chrome.

Comment: Which IE version? Does you document have a DOCTYPE so that the page is in Standards mode?

Comment: The problem occured in IE10.

Answer (score 1):

(Edited)

You can try max-width for IE-placeholder:

```
    :-ms-input-placeholder {  
       color: #0d1025;  
       font-style:italic;
       padding-left:15px;
       font-weight:bold;
       max-width:285px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but you misunderstood me. I want the inputs to have the size of 300px even when it's not focused.

Comment: Looks like I found the solution: box-sizing:border-box. Thanks for all your help!